# deep_const_ptr copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, smart-pointers

```
template <class T>
class deep_const_ptr
{
    T * priv;
public:
    deep_const_ptr(const deep_const_ptr & p_other); // copy ctor

    T const * operator->() const;
    T * operator->();
    ..... // other crap
};

void Cheese::doThings(const deep_const_ptr<Cheese> p_other)
{
    deep_const_ptr<Cheese> awayGoesTheConst(p_other); // I don't want this to work.
    awayGoesTheConst->doTerribleThings();
}
```

I'd like to block copy construction from a const to a non-const.

Maybe this doesn't even make any sense?

Might this be possible with the new C++11 / 14 / 17?

EDIT:

Yes, the issue is that if I don't give the copy constructor, STL containers wont work. And I'd quite need them to work.

EDIT:

deep_const_ptr was the solution what I came up with when faced with the problem of STL containers and const objects.

```
class Shape
{
    private:
        std::list<Vertex *> m_vertices;
    public:
        virtual void std::list<Vertex*> * const getVertices() { return &m_vertices; }
        virtual void std::list<Vertex const *> * const getVertices() const { return &m_vertices; } // doesn't work, cannot convert between different types of lists
}
```

I want to provide Immutable Vertex objects from an Immutable Shape.

The two solutions I came up with were custom deep_const_ptr pointer types and custom lists where

```
Vertex const *& operator[](unsigned int) const;
```

Comment: Please post code that actually demonstrates the problem you are having. This code compiles just fine if you change "iter" to "it" and add an appropriate Cheese class...

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood the problem my compiler was giving me, I changed the example to actually illustrate my problem. Don't know why I didn't write it like this from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you are after is a deep-const-pointer implementation and what to do with its copying. As you already found out, a simple copy constructor will not do, since you will just lose the const on your pointer. There is no other way to disallow the const removal on the outer object, so you just need to disable the copy constructor.
Now the current version of your question does not make it clear why that is a problem. From your comments and the previous question, I can only infer that you want to use the pointer in containers, std::vector<> specifically. The key to making that work is to disable copy, but enable move (Note that you need rvalue-reference support for this, which is part of C++11):

```
template <class T>
class deep_const_ptr
{
    T * priv;
public:
    deep_const_ptr(const deep_const_ptr &)  = delete; // Do not allow this!
    deep_const_ptr& operator=(const deep_const_ptr &) = delete; // Nor this!

    deep_const_ptr(deep_const_ptr &&) = default; // But this is okay
    deep_const_ptr& operator=(deep_const_ptr &&) = default; // So is this!

    T const * operator->() const;
    T * operator->();
    ..... // other crap
};
```

Containers typically only need move, not copy, to work.

If you really need support for the copy, you need to do it to a different type that only supports the const access. For example, you could specialize the `deep_const_ptr` for `const T` and only implement the const variant of `operator->` and `operator*` in there. Additionally, you'd allow "demotion" of a deep_const_ptr to a deep_const_ptr via the conversion operator. But this implies some sort of multiple owner handling, such as reference counting, so I'm going to leave it out. It's also weird that the const and non-const version behave differently, but it's your decision. Personally, I'd recommend just sticking with the move.

Comment: I didn't realize that the specialization would work for this. If you find the will to write it out, I would be most thankful. Although the move operation does sound a lot more sane, sadly I don't use C++11, yet!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Edit**: You updated your answer again, so let me reply to that.

Just use a `const` pointer:

```
void Cheese::doThings(const Cheese* p_other)
{
    Cheese* p = p_other; // compiler ERROR
    p->doTerribleThings(); // can not do terrible things
}
```

Or if you want a `shared_ptr`:

```
void Cheese::doThings(const std::shared_ptr<const Cheese>& p_other)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Cheese> p = p_other; // compiler ERROR
    p->doTerribleThings(); // can not do terrible things
}
```

`const ptr<T>` is not the same as `ptr<const T>`. The first indicates a pointer object which can not be changed, while the object pointed to can. The second indicates a pointer object which can be changed, but the object pointed to can not.

For a function signature `void foo(const A a)` does not make much sense. You say "give me a copy, and I promise to not change it". Who cares what you do with your copy? Use `void foo(const A& a)` to avoid creating a copy.

**Edit**:

> I'd like to allow copying nonconst -> nonconst, nonconst -> const,
>   const -> const.

This is already given for a "normal" pointer `T*` or an `std::shared_ptr`.

**Old**:

Just use `T* operator->() const;`. If the stored pointer will be a non-const pointer like `Cheese*` it can be converted to a `const Cheese*` automatically.

The function `operator->()` is marked as const, as it does not change the *pointer object* itself. This has nothing to do with the stored object!

Example with `vector`:

```
std::vector<Cheese*> a(10);
a[0] = 0; // does change a
Cheese* p = a[0]; // does not change a
a[0]->foo(); // still does not change a!
```

If you want objects pointed to by `deep_const_ptr` to be const, you have to use `deep_const_ptr<const Cheese>`.

Example with `vector`:

```
std::vector<const Cheese*> a(10); // const pointer!
a[0] = 0; // does change a 
const Cheese* p = a[0]; // does not change a
a[0]->foo(); // now this only works if Cheese::foo is const
```

Comment: Why would he want a "deep-const pointer" that does not have deep (but explicit, as you suggested) const?

Comment: @ltjax: What should "deep-const" mean? That does not make sense.

Comment: deep-const means that const is propagated to owned/held objects. For example, containers are usually deep-const (a const std::vector<> does not allow you to modify its contents!) while most smart pointers are explicitly shallow-const (e.g. shared_ptr<>, which does not propagate const, but allows you do specify it explictly)

Comment: I think that concept does not make sense for a pointer class.

Comment: Why not? Surely you could have an API that returns a const& to a container with those pointers inside. You might not want the clients to be able to modify the objects through this. Of course, you need to have sensible copy behavior for this to make sense: either deep copy or noncopyable seem to work - or allow "decay" to something parameterized with "const T". Just copying the pointer makes no sense, of course - since that would effectively just remove the const.

Comment: Isn't `const T*` exactly doing this, e.g. `const std::vector<const T*>&`?

Comment: Yes it is, but there is no easy way to convert between the two. And exactly what Itjax said.

Comment: @justanothercoder @ltjax: I really would like to understand your thoughts. "no easy way to convert": Pointers can be converted easily. `std::vector<S>` can to be automatically converted to `std::vector<T>` even if `S` can be converted to `T`. I do not see how this relates to pointers?

Comment: class Cheese { std::vector<S> m_things; std::vector<S> & getThings(); std::vector<S> const & getThings() const; }; If I used plain pointers as S, I could still change the objects they point to. So if I had const Cheese object, I could still change the things in it, thus changing the Cheese object. Now it's debatable if changing the objects listed in Cheese changes Cheese, but it's sufficient to say that this is the case sometimes. If I use deep_const_ptr instead of plain pointers, I can make sure that it's not possible to change those objects, without intentionally casting away the const.

Comment: Try `std::vector<const S> getThings() const;`. You can not force that behavior from outside onto `Cheese` by using a tricky  `deep_const_ptr`.

Comment: It's not quite painless to convert between std::vector<S *> and std::vector<S const *>. You would need to loop over the list and add the content to the new list.